# Angular JS Map : How to perform two way mapping of key

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am using Map in angular JS. on UI side i am iterating over the map. this key is used as a value for the date component. I want a functionality like if i change the date, the key should get changed.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: If your date-component is a directive, put the object.key as ng-model in date-component element

Comment: Why do you want change the key ? If your value in map stays constant then make that as key and date as value in map !